# loading different urls via WebView settings

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView app which loads a url, I want to create a Settings Activity where user can customize settings..
My que is, How to make a RadioButton or Chooser which when clicked will open the Mobile version of Site, Similarly if Desktop Ver. is clicked, webview will load Desktop version...

Answer (score 0):

By default webview loads mobile site, if you want to force load desktop site you can use

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

use radio button to choose this settings. Use `isChecked()` to check radio button else load normal webview.

Answer (score 0):

Below is WebView code.

```
public class WebViewLinks extends Activity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
        String Url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Url");
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(Url);
    }

    public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

You can use below code on button click or radio button selection.

```
Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(this, WebViewLinks.class);
webViewIntent.putExtra("Url", yourURL);
startActivity(webViewIntent);
```

see below example.

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if(checkedId == R.id.mobileview){
                    Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(this, WebViewLinks.class);
                    webViewIntent.putExtra("Url", mobileURL);
                    startActivity(webViewIntent);
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.desktopview){
                    Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(this, WebViewLinks.class);
                    webViewIntent.putExtra("Url", deskTopURL);
                    startActivity(webViewIntent);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below

```
     if(rbtnMobile.isChecked){
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
     webview.loadUrl(url);
    }else{
    webview.loadUrl(url);
   }
```